# C# WPF Animate Minimize/Maximize/Restore custom Window (WindowStyle.None && AllowsTransparency = true)

Tags: c#, wpf

As my title says, I need to animate this kind of window. I actually capture the WM_SYSCOMMAND and define the specific WindowState.

#### CodeSnippet:

```
    private System.IntPtr WindowProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam,ref bool handled)
    {
        var retVal = IntPtr.Zero;

        switch (msg) //http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/thread.php?postid=111901 Auflistung der WndProc-Message-Kommandos 
        {           
            case 0x0112: //https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx //WM_SYSCOMMAND message
                if ((int)wParam == 0xF120) //SC_RESTORE | Restores the window to its normal position and size.
                {
                    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    handled = true;
                }
                else if ((int) wParam == 0xF030) //SC_MAXIMIZE | Maximizes the window.
                {
                    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    handled = true;
                }
                else if ((int) wParam == 0xF020) //SC_MINIMIZE | Minimizes the window.
                {
                    WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                    handled = true;
                }
                break;
        }
       
        return retVal;
    }
```

Should I manually make a storyboard and calculate the new size and direction? Or is there another way to solve my problem?

*Change the WindowStyle before WindowState is no solution, because of "AllowsTransparency = true"*.

Regards

#### Edit:

I made a complete new style, that the app has always the same look (on every OS).

Window activated:

[image: Window activated]

Window deactivated:

[image: Window deactivated]

Window Language:

[image: Window deactivated]

On the taskbar is a comboBox to switch the languages live. Is has also a fade in/out effect on open/close Window.

Comment: I do not understand why using WindowProc?

Comment: for example, to capture the WM_NCACTIVATE message and "flash" the title bar.

Comment: Preview for flashing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44238110/6229375