# WPF Custom WindowChrome Minimize, Close actions no animation

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wpf-controls

I am creating a WPF app with a custom window chrome using the `<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>` tag and properties that go with it.  I implemented the Windows commands needed to correct the sizing issue for custom windows, and all of that is working great, however I notice that in standard windows (at least for Windows 10), when you minimize or close a window, it doesn't just disappear, you see a faint animation before the window is either minimized or closed.  In my custom window, when I execute either of these actions the window just vanishes, which isn't bad or anything, but if I want to mimic my custom window as closely to the standard as possible, I assume I would need to code that somewhere using something from user32?  Has anyone else noticed this before?  Is this just how it is for custom windows?

Notes: I am developing on .NET 4.5.2 in C#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39868811/1600) gave me the necessary clue:

> Change the WindowStyle before WindowState is no solution, because of "AllowsTransparency = true".

Indeed, if i use `WindowChrome` but *don't* set the `WindowStyle` to `None`, the animations work fine. It's only once you use transparency that this breaks. You didn't specify needing that, so maybe this is your solution!

Comment: i tried it out and for my use case it worked like a charm.  thanks for pointing this in the right direction!